# Ajax callback not happening while using jquery-ujs in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree, ujs

my controller is the extended version of [shipments_controller.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/api/app/controllers/spree/api/shipments_controller.rb) inside the file, `shipments_controller_decorator.rb`.

```
Spree::Api::ShipmentsController.class_eval do
  before_filter :find_and_update_shipment, only: [:ship, :ready, :add, :remove, :deliver]

  def deliver
    @shipment.deliver!
    respond_with(@shipment, default_template: :show)
  end
end
```

My route is :

```
put '/api/shipments/:id/deliver', :to => 'spree/api/shipments#deliver', :constraints => {:format => /json/} ,:as => "shipment_deliver"
```

Inside the *application.js* file, I have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.deliver.button.fa.fa-arrow-right').on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log("Hey!! I am there....")
    location.reload();
  });
})
```

I have the view *_shipment.html.erb* :

```
<div id="<%= "shipment_#{shipment.id}" %>" data-hook="admin_shipment_form">
  <%= render :partial => "spree/admin/variants/split", :formats => :js %>
  <fieldset class="no-border-bottom">
    <legend align="center" class="stock-location" data-hook="stock-location">
      <span class="shipment-number"><%= shipment.number %></span>
      -
      <span class="shipment-state"><%= Spree.t("shipment_states.#{shipment.state}") %></span>
      <%= Spree.t(:package_from) %>
      <strong class="stock-location-name" data-hook="stock-location-name">'<%= shipment.stock_location.name %>'</strong>
      <% if shipment.ready? and can? :update, shipment %>
        -
        <%= link_to Spree.t(:ship), '#', :class => 'ship button fa fa-arrow-right', :data => {'shipment-number' => shipment.number} %>
      <% elsif shipment.shipped? and can? :update, shipment %>
        -
        <%= link_to Spree.t(:deliver), main_app.shipment_deliver_path(shipment), {method: :put, :remote => true, data: {'shipment-number' => shipment.number}, :class => 'deliver button fa fa-arrow-right'} %>
      <% end %>
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
```

Now, when click on the *Deliver* link, the correct controller action is executing, and all data is getting updated to. But the only thing that is not happening *page reload*. The debugging `console.log` also not printing anything.

I looked [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) wiki link too, no luck!

Any idea how to fix ?

Comment: Isn't it `.on('ajaxSuccess')` instead of `ajax:success`?

Comment: @haim770 https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Does your `<a>` element has the `data-remote` attribute set?

Comment: @haim770 yes.. `remote: true` option does it..

Comment: @haim770 I checked in Browser.. Ajax call is happening. Just the event is not getting called.

Comment: @Legendary not getting you..

Comment: @Legendary It is there.. when the `<% elsif shipment.shipped? and can? :update, shipment %>` true.

Comment: and then, if it ok - try it to your link, and if no - we will think

Comment: tried.. log is not printing any data..

Comment: You tried it exactly on $(document) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found one [work around](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/gdP5m-mgpRQ).

When I put the overridden file in  `vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/shipments.js.erb`, it doesn't work.

It worked when I put in 
`app/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/shipments.js.erb`.

Working Jquery code:

```
//handle deliver click
  $('[data-hook=admin_shipment_form] a.deliver').on('click', function () {
    var link = $(this);
    var shipment_number = link.data('shipment-number');
    var url = Spree.url(Spree.routes.shipments_api + '/' + shipment_number + '/deliver.json');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: url
    }).done(function () {
      window.location.reload();
    }).error(function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });
```

And the relevant view html content is :

```
<div id="<%= "shipment_#{shipment.id}" %>" data-hook="admin_shipment_form">
  <%= render :partial => "spree/admin/variants/split", :formats => :js %>
  <fieldset class="no-border-bottom">
    <legend align="center" class="stock-location" data-hook="stock-location">
      <span class="shipment-number"><%= shipment.number %></span>
      -
      <span class="shipment-state"><%= Spree.t("shipment_states.#{shipment.state}") %></span>
      <%= Spree.t(:package_from) %>
      <strong class="stock-location-name" data-hook="stock-location-name">'<%= shipment.stock_location.name %>'</strong>
      <% if shipment.ready? and can? :update, shipment %>
        -
        <%= link_to Spree.t(:ship), '#', :class => 'ship button fa fa-arrow-right', :data => {'shipment-number' => shipment.number} %>
      <% elsif shipment.shipped? and can? :update, shipment %>
        -
        <%= link_to Spree.t(:deliver), '#', :class => 'deliver button fa fa-arrow-right', :data => {'shipment-number' => shipment.number} %>
      <% end %>
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the following [gist suggestions](https://gist.github.com/aruprakshit/d6d78d10624b26d067d7) worked, I think you will have to send a json response back to ajax to make it receive a response it understands. Like so:

```
respond_with(@shipment, default_template: :show) do |format|
  format.html { render }
  format.json { render json: @shipment }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "remote: true" and not jquery native Ajax, try the following solution:

When you use "remote: true" to execute ajax calls to the server (with ruby on rails of course ), you hit a certain action in the controller. In your case this action is "deliver". In that action, you should respond with **js** and send the data you want back to the client. for example:

```
respond_with(@shipment, default_template: :show) do |format|
 format.html 
 format.js 
end
```

After that, you should create ( in the respected views directory ) a file, named after the action, but not html or haml, but js. So if your controller is named "**ShippmentsController**" and your action is "**deliver**", then you should create a file named "**app/views/shippments**/*deliver.js.erb*". In there you can write the jquery/javascript that should be executed when the Ajax will be completed.

Comment: Why it is not working inside the application.js file ?

Comment: As far as I know, it has to do with jquery.ujs. You could use Jquery's ajax instead of "remote-true".

Comment: Any idea what that default html template will do there ? Not able to understand that too..

Comment: any idea how should I send the status ?

Comment: The default html template should not be rendered, as the controller should respond as format.js. Otherwise, it should render the html template as usual, but the expected changes ( ajax response ) will never happen.